# Which method is suitable when the independent variables are of process steps over time and the dependent is binary?

Tags: time-series, logistic, repeated-measures, growth-model

I'm quite confused with some methods I've read about - growth models, repeated measures, time-series fixed effects models etc. I'm trying to understand which method is most suitable to the data I have.

I have a large dataset, describing a process that each individual is going through. Each individual has its own data about day1, day2, day3... until the end of the process (the duration is different for all the individuals but I can normalize it if needed to 10% of the time, 20% etc.). I have for each such individual a single binary dependent variable indicating the end of the process - pass/fail. I want to measure the associations of the values of the different steps on the outcome variables, but not only the values themselves but also "the process". I mean, I don't want to put each step as a single observation and then group it all by the individual, because the values of the variables at day2 should not be regarded as those at day20....

Any help would be very much appreciated, I read a lot of material about the different models available and still can't understand what is best for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like (discrete time) survival data to me. Maybe looking at survival analysis,  event history analysis, duration analysis or transition analysis helps?

Comment: But aren't survival models used for predicting the overall rate of success? I need to find how a specific variable affects the chances to succeed..

Comment: Still sounds like a survival analysis model to me. You don't give enough details to say anything more than just that. I suggest you just read up on this technique and decide if that is what you want. When it is not what you want edit the question to say why that is not what you want. That often helps to pin down the problem.